# Show that the series $\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{1}{k^4}$ is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis

Show that the series $\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{1}{k^4}$ is bounded.

What I've tried: Since

$\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{3^4}\leq \frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{2^4}=\frac{1}{2^3}$

$\frac{1}{4^4}+\frac{1}{5^4}+\frac{1}{6^4}+\frac{1}{7^4}\leq \frac{1}{4^4}+\frac{1}{4^4}+\frac{1}{4^4}+\frac{1}{4^4}=\frac{1}{4^3}$

and so on. So the series in question is less than $1+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{4^3}+\frac{1}{8^3}...$. If I can show the latter is bounded I'm done. But I can't so maybe there is and easier solution?

Comment: For $k\ge 2$, $$
\frac{1}{{k^4 }} \le \frac{1}{{k^2 }} \le \frac{1}{{k(k - 1)}} = \frac{1}{{k - 1}} - \frac{1}{k}.
$$ Or not that your final sume is $\sum_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{8^k }}} $.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{0^4} = ??$$

Comment: Hint: you're doing Cauchy Condensation and forcing powers of two in the denominators... remember, power-to-a-power - it makes a superpower! (Less cryptic hint: Try to force a geometric series.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, be careful with your index of summation - your series is not defined at $k = 0$. Anyways, note that $\frac{1}{k^4} \leq \frac{1}{k^2}$ for each positive integer $k$. Thus,

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^4} \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Comment: damn, I know the basel series so I should've seen this.

Comment: How do we known that $\sum k^{-2}$ converges to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$? You could have just told the exact value of $\sum k^{-4}$ as well ($\frac{\pi^4}{90}$).

Comment: @Gary That's a fair criticism. My experience has been that the Basel problem is generally much more well-known among undergraduates - it's usually the first (and sometimes only) explicit example of a convergent p-series, so I started from there.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^4}
\leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}
= 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(k + 1\right)^2}
\leq 1+\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2} dx
= 1 + 1
= 2
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2):

Without resorting to known p-series, do the following: You've already done part of the work in comparing subsets of terms via a Cauchy-condensation-type move. The next step is to realize that $4 = 2^2, 8 = 2^3,$ and so on. You then have

$$ \sum_{j \geq 1} \frac{1}{(2^3)^{j-1}} = \sum_{j \geq 1} \left( \frac{1}{8} \right)^{j-1} = \frac{8}{7}$$

(you should check this by using the geometric series formula). Thus by comparison we have

$$ \sum_{j \geq 1} \frac{1}{j^4} \leq \frac{8}{7}.$$

Notice that this estimate is off by $-0.060533$ from the actual value of the sum of $\frac{\pi^4}{90}.$